# Need to show a custom shape overlay in the in-built camera application

Tags: android, camera, overlay

I am trying to show a custom shape overlay in the in-built camera application which I am opening by intent as I want the user take the photo inside that shape only. I have already created the overlay by using onDraw() method of my class which extends to view. How can I show the overlay in that camera?
I found a few solutions, but all them are using either using Camera2 or CameraX to do this. But, I want to do this while using the in-built camera.
I am calling this function in my clickListener of the button which opens the camera.

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible.  You cannot modify other applications with your own drawing code.